# when iterating 2 columns for duplicates no output is shown even when there are duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am iterating through 2 columns. When I find a duplicate I want to output the value corresponding to that row of some other column. I used the following logic:

```
n = df.values


val = 0
cpval=0
i=0
for id,cp in zip(n[:,2:3],n[:,1:2]):
    if(id is val and cp is cpval):
        print(id)
        print(n[i,11])
        print(val)
        print(n[i-1,11])
        val=id
        cpval=cp
    else:
        val=id
        cpval=cp
    i=i+1
```

The index slicing is correct and everything is fine but no output is shown, and when I see it manually there are duplicates. The `else` part is working fine.

`n[:,2:3]` is a float type

`n[:,1:2]` is an object type

Is the logic wrong? What is wrong with the code?

example of dataframe-

```
2013J   538210
2013B   538211
2013B   538221
2013B   538232
2013B   538232
2013B   538251
2013B   538611
2013B   538701
2013J   538863
2013J   538887
2014B   538887
2013B   538897
2013J   538903
```

for this data I want the output -

```
538232
Fail      #(this value is in another column at n[i,11], i is the count 
            of the row)
538232
Withdrawn
```

when I printed id and cd one of the elements is like this-

```
(array([3733], dtype=object), array(['2013J'], dtype=object))
```

can this be the problem

Comment: Could you show an example of `df`?

Comment: I have added example data

Comment: Could you now also provide your desired outcome for this input and describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added the desired output

Comment: when I printed one id and cp the values are like this-  (array([3733], dtype=object), array(['2013J'], dtype=object))  can this be the problem?